# How to query all values which share the same value in another field as the value on that row?

Tags: sql, db2

Sorry for the awkwardly-phrased title; I couldn't think of another way to describe this problem!

I have a table (lets call it table1) which looks roughly like this:

```
OFFER | DEAL
------------
 A    | 1
 B    | 1
 C    | 1
 D    | 2
 E    | 2
 F    | 3
```

I want to write a query which lists all offers and their deal number, along with an additional field showing any offers which share that deal number.

In other words, the results should look like this:

```
OFFER | DEAL | SHARED
---------------------
 A    | 1    | B
 A    | 1    | C
 B    | 1    | A
 B    | 1    | C
 C    | 1    | A
 C    | 1    | B
 D    | 2    | E
 E    | 2    | D
```

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join:

```
select t1.*, t2.offer
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.deal = t2.deal and t1.offer <> t2.offer;
```